# How to properly display json in angular directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have angular app that uses ui-router and I have set service and directive but can't display json data. It works fine without directive when I just display it in main template (home.html).
My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'homeList', function ($scope, homeList) {
    homeList.get().then(function (homeList) {
        $scope.homeList = homeList;
        $scope.homeList.name = 'Home list';
    });
}]);
```

and when I do `{{homeList.name}}` it displays correctly but `ng-repeat` in `directiveTemplate.html` doesn't display data from json.

Here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GTfLFQepFcXzXYcIHnP0

There are no errors in console so I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line in `home.html`:

```
<li home-list homeList="homeList"></li>
```

Here you are using a `home-list` attribute, which is your directive, but with no value. Then you are using an attribute `homeList` which is not bound to anything.

Remember that angular works in lower case in the HTML, so in short it should be:

```
<li home-list="homeList"></li>
```

See it working in that plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xD4UmUj80wiLOXZqYFyK?p=preview